# chart like RaVis using js charts library

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, svg, charts, data-visualization

I have a chart which is currently implemented in [RaVis](http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ravis/RaVisExamples/example-binaries/RaVisExplorer.html#) which uses flex.

I want to implement the same chart using JavaScript/SVG chart library but so far I haven't found a suitable solution.

I can't even put a name to this chart.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**D3.js** has a pretty similar radial tree that you could bend to suit your needs :

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

More examples : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery